# Log scale for forest plot without changing hazard ratio values or x-axis tick marks

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am trying to use a log scale on my forest plot of hazard ratios. I input the hazard ratio estimates and confidence intervals by hand into my plot, but I need the same values (unchanged) to be on a log scale when plotted. Preferably with the same tick marks as the plot currently has on the arithmetic scale. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried atransf = exp, which changes all my hazard ratios. 
I also tried at = log(c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6)), which changes all the tick marks drastically. How can I convert to the log scale without changing the numeric tick marks of my axes and the values of my hazards?

Thanks for your help.

```
#Forest Plot
label1 <- as.character(c("<50", "50 to <60", "60"))
label1 <- factor(label1, levels = unique(label1))
hazards1 <- c(1.42, 1.66, 2.85)
lower1 <- c(1.34, 1.50, 2.59)
upper1 <- c(1.51, 1.85, 3.13)
patient_num1 <- c(240000, 180000, 220000)
event_num1 <- c(2600, 1300, 2900)
forestplot1 <- data.frame(label1, hazards1, lower1, upper1, event_num1, patient_num1)
forestplot1$patient_num1 <- rev(forestplot1$patient_num1)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))
pdf(file = "figureex.pdf", width = 15, height = 8.5)
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
forest(rev(hazards1), ci.lb = rev(lower1), ci.ub = rev(upper1), slab = rev(label1), xlim = c(-4,0), 
       xlab = "Adjusted Hazard Ratio for Event", 
       refline = 1, annotate = T, ylim = c(-1, 29), ilab = cbind(forestplot1$patient_num1, rev(event_num1)),
       ilab.xpos=c(-1,-0.25), at = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6), rows = c(1:3),
       cex = 1, yaxs = "i")
text(-4, 27.29, pos = 4, "Variable")
text(-1.25, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nPatients")
text(-0.45, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nEvents")
text(5.05, 27.69, pos = 4, "Hazard Ratio \n(95% CI)")
dev.off()
```

Comment: I can't run your code, I get the following error `no applicable method for 'forest' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`, do you only load the package `meta` or do you load another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `forest` function in the `metafor` package. The function `forestplot` in the package `forestplot` allows you to specify the tick marks with `xticks` as well as use log scale for the tick marks with `xlog`.